# Synchronization issue in a cluster

Tags: java, synchronization, hazelcast, jgroups, distributed-objects

I have two programs both of them are running on a cluster. My problem is that there is a problem about synchronization on the shared objects when the two programs are started at the same time. If I start two programs simultaneously, they almost don't manage to see other's work on the object.

For example,

```java
HazelcastInstance instance = Hazelcast.newHazelcastInstance(cfg);
IMap<Object,Object> lockMap = instance.getMap("someMap");

// start lock
lockMap.lock("someLock");
System.out.println("nodeId="+nodeId+" "+System.currentTimeMillis()+" lock ");

// put entry to the map
lockMap.put(nodeId,"value");

//  point 1
int size=lockMap.size();
System.out.println("nodeId="+nodeId+" size = "+size);

// end lock

System.out.println("nodeId="+nodeId+" "+System.currentTimeMillis()+" unlock ");
lockMap.unlock("someLock");
```

Output is:

7f653993-cd63-4246-946a-e7a141fa477e 1485417274993 lock    
7f653993-cd63-4246-946a-e7a141fa477e size = 1 
7f653993-cd63-4246-946a-e7a141fa477e 1485417274994 unlock

c11399ec-8242-4e80-b9e9-0f43a050590c 1485417348313 lock   
c11399ec-8242-4e80-b9e9-0f43a050590c size = 1 
c11399ec-8242-4e80-b9e9-0f43a050590c 1485417348315 unlock

When debugging every time I'm sure that between start and end lock there will be only one node and at the point 1 size will be printed appropriately. However, when I run two nodes simultaneously at point 1 each node prints "size = 1" . It seems like the second node isn't aware of up-to-date status of the map.

How can I be sure that every node will see the recent information on the map. I have used Jgroups, it has similar problems as well.

Any help will be appreciated,

Thanks

Comment: What is the value of `nodeId` in each thread?  Change the print to `System.out.println("nodeId="+nodeId+" size = "+size);` and show us the output.

Comment: I have added the output and the time. Both programs are running on the same machine and two different jvms.

Comment: Maybe the problem is nodes didn't find each other and didn't form a cluster. Search logs for such a message 

```Members [2] {
 Member [192.168.2.26]:5702 - 3919e352-0f16-4404-908d-cbdade6a297e this
 Member [192.168.2.26]:5701 - 9cdebcd7-9d92-4f42-8b0a-cca9facf9c71
}```

If you see above message, it means nodes found each other and can see latest state of the shared map.